# Passing params to Freeform’s `render` tag

Tags: plugin-freeform

Can you pass params to Freeform’s `render` tag ?

E.g. `{{ entry.form.render({ entry: entry }) }}` ?

Trying to access `entry` data inside formatting templates...but I get `Variable "entry" does not exist` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't possible right now, the things you *can* pass to the `render` tag are listed here under [`customAttributes`](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform/docs/form/#prop-custom-attributes).

We might, however, add such functionality in the future.